# Trying to add an element to existing xml file with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I've been trying to get xmlstarlet to add `<security-enabled>false</security-enabled>` to "/configuration/core".  The command runs without error, but now changes are made to the file.

The XML file:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <jms xmlns="urn:activemq:jms">
    <queue name="DLQ"/>
    <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
  </jms>
  <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
    <!-- this could be ASYNCIO or NIO
       -->
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>./data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <journal-min-files>10</journal-min-files>
    ...
  </core>
</configuration>
```

One of the commands I have run:

```
xmlstarlet ed -i "/configuration/core" -t attr -n "security-enabled" -v "false"  broker.xml
```

I have also used *xmlstarlet ed -L ...* to edit in place, but when I noticed the edits weren't happening I dropped -L for STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [specify xml namespace properly](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html). In your case:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -N a="urn:activemq" -N c="urn:activemq:core" -s "/a:configuration/c:core" -t elem -n "security-enabled" -v "false" broker.xml
```

Moreover I changed:

- `-t attr` to `-t elem` since we need element instead of attribute
- `-i` to `-s` since we are asking for *sub* element to be added